# "Primary Key should be unique SQLite" Error 

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my main `Activity` in which I am doing my all work. I am getting error in creating the `SQLite` database.

```
private final String DB_NAME = "pocketCloudlets";
private final String TABLE_NAME_1 = "Members";
long count = 0;
static final String userTable="user";

static final String userName = "User";
static final String userID = "_id";
static final String age ="age";
static final String gender = "gender";
static final String password = "password";
static final String email = "email";

// Creating Table for User Record  

protected static final String table1=(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
    + userTable + " ("
    + userID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
    + userName + " VARCHAR ,"
    + age + " VARCHAR ,"
    + gender + " VARCHAR )");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

        try {      
            sampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            sampleDB.execSQL(table1);

            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                userTable +
                " Values ('13','dawdaa','4','female');");

            Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id,userName, age, gender FROM " +
                userTable + " ", null);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // completed by the editor of this question
            // the 'catch' part of the try-catch structure was NOT present
        }
```

Comment: Show the error you get by posting the logcat

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this worked the first time you started the activity. Now you have inserted the one row with `_id = 13` and now, every time you do this again, you'd create the same id over and over again.

As you've specified `_id` to be the primary key of the table, this is not allowed -- primary key must be unique.

Comment: Beat me to it. +1 The select query is also broken though as biegleux points out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id,userName, age, gender FROM " +
    userTable + " ", null);
```

You have no `userName` column in the table, instead you created the table with the `user` column.

Use instead:

```
Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id, user, age, gender FROM " + userTable, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the userID column to Integer Primary Key AutoIncrement.  I am also pretty sure you can't use VARCHAR in sqlite - you need to use TEXT instead.  Check out this link for reference: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: It isn't necessary to use `AUTOINCREMENT` and `VARCHAR` is valid for `SQLite`.